# Do I have to use GLAD loader in SFML app?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I'm using openGL 3.3 to render a 3D scene in an SFML window. 
Do I still have to use GLAD in order to load openGL library or is loader already implemented into the sf::RenderWindow class?

Comment: You should read up on SFML / OpenGL integration tutorials supplied by both libraries' sites, https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-opengl.php and https://open.gl/context (scroll to SFML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need a loader like GLAD to find the opengl functions.